# how to re-render after getting axios response in jest test

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, jestjs, axios

My component:

```
componentDidMount() {
    // Make HTTP reques with Axios
    axios.get(APIConfig.api_profile()).then((res) => {
        // Set state with result
        this.setState(res.data);
        console.log('I was triggered during componentDidMount')
        console.log(res)
    });
}
```

And my test:

```
//@see https://github.com/ctimmerm/axios-mock-adapter
mock.onGet(APIConfig.api_profile()).reply(200, {
    "id_user": "1",
    "id_person": "1",
    "imageUrl": "",
    "email": "xyz@zyz.com",
    "name": "xyz xyz"
});

test('xyz', async() => {

    var ProfilePic2 =require('../../src/views/ProfilePic');
    const component = renderer.create(
        <ProfilePic/>
    );

    expect(component.state).toBeDefined();
    //tree.props.setProfile({})
    let tree = component.toJSON();
    await expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

The problem is that jest is testing on initial render while I need to test it after a API response is received. Therefore the snapshot that it is comparing to is also mostly empty.

I am not able make the test wait till after the second render.
I am just trying await/async but cannot get it to work.
I can see my api mocs was called from the console log.

Comment: When using enzime, mounted components have a update() method, after I change the store state I call that, maybe there is something similar you can use?

Comment: Can you change state from the unit? If possible, that could partly solve my problem. Then I would just test my mock api call separately and my render separately (using given state).

Comment: There is a simple method how to achieve this. https://browse-tutorials.com/snippet/react-wait-full-render-snapshot-testing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that jest does not wait for async calls, have a look at the docs [here](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/asynchronous.html#content). So the way how can you solve this is to give jest the promise that `axios.get` returns. This will not work if you use something that just mocks the async call inside axios. You have to mock `axios` complete out of your test like this:

```
jest.mock('axios', ()=> ({get:jest.fn()}))
```

now when importing `axios` into your file it will get an object where the get function is just a spy. To implement the spy so it will return a promise that you can give to jest you have to import it into your test:

```
import {get} from axios
```

now in your test create a resolved promise

```
test('xyz', async() = > {
  const p = Promise.resolve({
    data: {
      "id_user": "1",
      "id_person": "1",
      "imageUrl": "",
      "email": "xyz@zyz.com",
      "name": "xyz xyz"
    }
  })
  get.mockImplementation(() => p)
  var ProfilePic2 = require('../../src/views/ProfilePic');
  const component = renderer.create(
    <ProfilePic/>
  );
  expect(component.state).toBeDefined();
  //tree.props.setProfile({})
  let tree = component.toJSON();
  await p
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

Btw. I'm not sure if `react-test-renderer` will call `componentDidMount`, maybe you have to switch to enzyme.

Comment: did not work. axious error is getting called "Error: Warning: setState(...): You passed an undefined or null state object;"

Comment: CHANGED TO: const p = Promise.resolve({"data": {"id_user": "1", "id_person": "1", "imageUrl": "", "email": "xyz@zyz.com", "name": "xyz xyz"}}) and then got it to work. :)