# Spying on React child component method

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme, spy

I am trying to test my React component with jest and enzyme. I have a form component that uses `react-skylight` component. I am triggering `.show()` function on form submit and just when response from server is successful.

My test is currently like this:

```
import MyForm from './MyForm';
import Popup from 'react-skylight';

describe('<MyForm />', () => {
    it('should show popup on success', () => {
        const popupShowSpy = jest.spyOn(Popup.prototype, 'show');
        const myForm = mount(<MyForm />);
        myForm.update();

        myForm.find('form').simulate('submit');
        expect(popupShowSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

but I am getting an error when I run tests:

```
expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()

Expected mock function to have been called.
```

I found [here](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/365) discusion about similar problem, but for me it is not working.

---

Solution:

Problem was with `axios` module. It was updating the component, but the response taht was mocked was not resolved, so thanks to this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43706501/how-to-re-render-after-getting-axios-response-in-jest-test), I've managed to write tests. And I wrapped the child components function call in parent component own function and spied on that parent function.

```
import MyForm from './MyForm';
import Popup from 'react-skylight';

describe('<MyForm />', () => {
    it('should show popup on success', async() => {
        const popupShowSpy = jest.spyOn(MyForm.prototype, 'showPopup');
        const myForm = mount(<MyForm />);

        const response = Promise.resolve({
          data: {
              message: 'Error: some error'
          },
          status: 400
        });
        axios.post = jest.fn(() => response);
        myForm.find('form').simulate('submit');
        await response;
        myForm.update(); // <- child component is rendered correctly
        expect(popupShowSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

Comment: You might wanna rethink your title. Spying on children is illegal in most places

Comment: Please officially answer and accept your own answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

Problem was with `axios` module. It was updating the component, but the response that was mocked was not resolved, so thanks to this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43706501/how-to-re-render-after-getting-axios-response-in-jest-test), I've managed to write tests. And I wrapped the child components function call in parent component own function and spied on that parent function.

```
import MyForm from './MyForm';
import Popup from 'react-skylight';

describe('<MyForm />', () => {
    it('should show popup on success', async() => {
        const popupShowSpy = jest.spyOn(MyForm.prototype, 'showPopup');
        const myForm = mount(<MyForm />);

        const response = Promise.resolve({
          data: {
              message: 'Error: some error'
          },
          status: 400
        });
        axios.post = jest.fn(() => response);
        myForm.find('form').simulate('submit');
        await response;
        myForm.update(); // <- child component is rendered correctly
        expect(popupShowSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```